# Using an SVG icon in a pseudo element, with control over size and color?

Tags: css, svg, icons

I am hoping to achieve something like this:

```
Link >
```

Where the `>` is an SVG icon.

I am using icomoon.io's "chevron-right" icon and loading icons by inlining the icon sprite file (included, with only this icon).

I reference other icons inline and that works OK.

```
<svg class="icon"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#icon-menu"></use></svg>

.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  stroke-width: 0;
  stroke: black;
  fill: currentColor;
  width: 1.1em;
  height: 1.1em;
}
```

I am looking for a way to reference the icon in a pseudo element so I can easily style all links with it.

So far the only way I've found is to inline it, but I can't seem to control the size or color -- whether I use it as a background image or as content.

```
.-with-trailing-chevron:after  {
  content: "";
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'%3E%3Cpath fill='##4A89AA' d='M15.7 11.3l-6-6c-0.4-0.4-1-0.4-1.4 0s-0.4 1 0 1.4l5.3 5.3-5.3 5.3c-0.4 0.4-0.4 1 0 1.4 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.7 0.3s0.5-0.1 0.7-0.3l6-6c0.4-0.4 0.4-1 0-1.4z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-image-size: cover; // these don't seem to work
  display: inline-block;
  width: .8em; // these don't seem to work on the icon
  height: .8em; // these don't seem to work on the icon
}
```

Also, would much prefer to reference it instead of inlining.

Are these possible?

Icons sprite file, which I currently inline to avoid ie incompatibilities:

```
<svg aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
<symbol id="icon-chevron-right" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
<title>chevron-right</title>
<path d="M15.7 11.3l-6-6c-0.4-0.4-1-0.4-1.4 0s-0.4 1 0 1.4l5.3 5.3-5.3 5.3c-0.4 0.4-0.4 1 0 1.4 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.7 0.3s0.5-0.1 0.7-0.3l6-6c0.4-0.4 0.4-1 0-1.4z"></path>
</symbol>
</defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to use the chevron SVG as a background image instead of a real physical element in your markup ? Alternatively, have you tried using the 'content' attribute rather than the background-image for assigning the pseudo element? You may be able to change color, and size of the element if it's part of the content attribute rather than the background-image (untested).

Comment: Tried the content attribute; did not add more control; I think my main issue is with scaling, in both situations. And, the need to inline the element in the css. I will likely end up using the icon as an svg reference in the html, was hoping to clean up the markup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Data urls are treated as inert images that do not allow external (to the data url!) references. You need to set their properties **inside** the svg code. So if you want to change size and color, only this will work:

```css
a::after {
    content: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg width="1em" height="1em" fill="green" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M15.7 11.3l-6-6c-0.4-0.4-1-0.4-1.4 0s-0.4 1 0 1.4l5.3 5.3-5.3 5.3c-0.4 0.4-0.4 1 0 1.4 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.7 0.3s0.5-0.1 0.7-0.3l6-6c0.4-0.4 0.4-1 0-1.4z"></path></svg>');
    vertical-align: -0.2em;
    padding-left: 0.1em;
}
a:hover::after {
    content: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg width="1.2em" height="1.2em" fill="red" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M15.7 11.3l-6-6c-0.4-0.4-1-0.4-1.4 0s-0.4 1 0 1.4l5.3 5.3-5.3 5.3c-0.4 0.4-0.4 1 0 1.4 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.7 0.3s0.5-0.1 0.7-0.3l6-6c0.4-0.4 0.4-1 0-1.4z"></path></svg>');
    vertical-align: -0.3em;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="">Link</a>
```

As you can see, positioning can still be modified by CSS.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is a solution I can use. I was getting tripped by the quotes/double quotes in the content: definition and by some positioning issues which the vertical-align property solved.